# v.context.$implicit.(PropertyName)is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

i Need to User Dynamic Permission in Angular6 .

i must return list of menu from database :

```
  <li *ngFor="let op of optionList">
    <!-- <fa-icon [icon]="op.icon"></fa-icon>  -->
    <label (click)='op.routeFunctionName()'>{{op.optionName}}</label>
  </li>
```

this : `op.routeFunctionName()` Function Name for Using Routing .

Routing :

```
 GoRoleManager(){
     this.router.navigate(['panel/dashboard/'+this.userName+'/role'])
 }
```

but it show me this error when i click the menu :

> ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.routeFunctionName is not a function

Whats the Problem ? how Can i Solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had saved JS code in `routeFunctionName` and tried calling it. It's just plain text. If you want to do it, you can do it with `eval` but that is **not recommended**.

**Update** (see comments)

If you want to call a function by string variable you should write like this:

```
<label (click)='this[op.routeFunctionName]()'>{{op.optionName}}</label>
```

Comment: @kianoush in that case, try `this[op.routeFunctionName]()` instead of `op.routeFunctionName()`